# Two Poisson Process related together

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have this exercise problem in stochastic process textbook.

A worker has a number of machines to repair. Each time a repair is completed a new one is begun. Each repair independently takes an exponential amount of time with rate $μ$ to complete. However, independent of this, mistakes occur according to a Poisson process with rate $λ$. Whenever a mistake occurs, the item is ruined and work is started on a new item. In the long run how often are jobs completed?

At first I thought this would just be $\frac{t}{N(t)-M(t)}$ where $N(t)$ is the Poisson process for fixing machines and $M(t)$ for the Poisson process of mistakes. But then I realized the repairing would stop one a mistake happens, so it’s not really $N(t)$. What should I do?

Comment: "A worker has a number of machines to repair." - is this a finite number, say $N$, or is it assumed to be infinite?

Comment: The probability that a machine is repaired correctly is $\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}$.

Comment: @math1000 I suppose it’s infinite

Comment: @math1000 Can you explain why?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually $1-\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu} = \frac\mu{\lambda+\mu}$. As for why, it is the probability that one exponentially distributed random variable is less than another, which is known to be of that form. Recall that the times between arrivals in a Poisson process are exponentially distributed.

Comment: @math1000 Yes. But is this the same as the probability that one exponential is less than another? The setup of this problem seems rather complex. I can’t express the desired variable in math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_i$ represent the time spent repairing the $i^\text{th}$ machine. Then $T_i=\min\{X_i,Y_i\}$ where $X_i\sim\text{Exp}(\mu)$ and $Y_i\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for all $i$. Since $T_i$ are iid the question is just asking for $\mathbb{P}(T_i=X_i)$ which is $\mu/(\mu+\lambda)$.